# json.net ExtensionData Modify json key name when deserializing

Tags: c#, json.net, deserialization

I'm using the `JsonExtensionData` Attribute along with a `Dictionary<string, object>`, which actually works pretty well for all my "unknown" JSON results.

Unfortunately the JSON string I get from my webservice sometimes gives me keys with non-alphanumeric characters, which I want to cleanup during deserialization.

For example:

```
"dc:title":"My Document title"
```

During deserialization I want to remove all non-alphanumeric characters and I wonder if there is an easy way to do so with a custom converter?

Derserializer Code

```
public class TikaDeserializer : IDeserializer
{
    private Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer serializer;


    public TikaDeserializer(Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        this.serializer = serializer;
    }

    public T Deserialize<T>(RestSharp.IRestResponse response)
    {
        var content = response.Content;

        using(var stringReader = new StringReader(content))
        {
            using(var jsonTextReader = new JsonTextReader(stringReader))
            {
                return serializer.Deserialize<T>(jsonTextReader);
            }
        }
    }

    public string DateFormat { get; set; }

    public string Namespace { get; set; }

    public string RootElement { get; set; }

    public static TikaDeserializer Default
    {
        get
        {
            return new TikaDeserializer(new Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer()
            {
                NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore,
            });
        }
    }
```

Converter Code by Gediminas

```
public class InputKeyNameCleanerConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return objectType.IsGenericType && objectType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(Dictionary<,>);
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        var jObject = JToken.ReadFrom(reader);
        foreach(JToken token in jObject.ToList())
        {
            string replacedName = Regex.Replace(token.Path, @"[^A-Za-z]", String.Empty);
            JProperty newToken = new JProperty(replacedName, token.First);
            token.Replace(newToken);
        }
        return jObject.ToObject(objectType);
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException();
    }
}
```

Model

```
public class ParsedDocument
{

    [JsonProperty("Author")]
    public string Author { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("Content-Type")]
    public string ContentType { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("Content-Encoding")]
    public string ContentEncoding { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("Creation-Date")]
    public DateTime? DateCreated { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("Last-Modified")]
    public DateTime? DateModified { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("Last-Save-Date")]
    public DateTime? DateSaved { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("Last-Printed")]
    public DateTime? DatePrinted { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("title")]
    public string Title { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("X-TIKA:content")]
    public string Content { get; set; }

    [JsonExtensionData]
    public Dictionary<string, object> MetaData { get; set; }




}
```

Comment: try using dynamic like so (dynamic data = deserialiseJson(JsonString);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using a [custom contract resolver](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/ContractResolver.htm) that replaces the [`JsonObjectContract.ExtensionDataSetter`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/P_Newtonsoft_Json_Serialization_JsonObjectContract_ExtensionDataSetter.htm) delegate:

```
public class ExtensionNameMappingContractResolver : IContractResolver
{
    readonly IContractResolver baseResolver;
    readonly Regex regex;
    readonly string replacement;

    // As of 7.0.1, Json.NET suggests using a static instance for "stateless" contract resolvers, for performance reasons.
    // http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/ContractResolver.htm
    // http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_Serialization_DefaultContractResolver__ctor_1.htm
    // "Use the parameterless constructor and cache instances of the contract resolver within your application for optimal performance."

    static ExtensionNameMappingContractResolver removeNonAlphanumericCharactersInstance;

    static ExtensionNameMappingContractResolver()
    {
        // Regex is from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8779189/how-do-i-strip-non-alphanumeric-characters-including-spaces-from-a-string
        removeNonAlphanumericCharactersInstance = new ExtensionNameMappingContractResolver(new DefaultContractResolver(), new Regex(@"[^\p{L}\p{N}]+"), "");
    }

    public static ExtensionNameMappingContractResolver RemoveNonAlphanumericCharactersInstance { get { return removeNonAlphanumericCharactersInstance; } }

    public ExtensionNameMappingContractResolver(IContractResolver baseResolver, Regex regex, string replacement)
    {
        if (regex == null || replacement == null || baseResolver == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException();
        this.regex = regex;
        this.replacement = replacement;
        this.baseResolver = baseResolver;
    }

    #region IContractResolver Members

    public JsonContract ResolveContract(Type type)
    {
        var contract = baseResolver.ResolveContract(type);
        if (contract is JsonObjectContract)
        {
            var objContract = (JsonObjectContract)contract;
            if (objContract.ExtensionDataSetter != null)
            {
                var oldSetter = objContract.ExtensionDataSetter;
                objContract.ExtensionDataSetter = (o, key, value) =>
                {
                    var newKey = regex.Replace(key, replacement);
                    oldSetter(o, newKey, value);
                };
            }
        }
        return contract;
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Then use it like:

```
        var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings 
        {
             NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore,
            ContractResolver = ExtensionNameMappingContractResolver.RemoveNonAlphanumericCharactersInstance 
        };
        var serializer = JsonSerializer.CreateDefault(settings);
```

Note that the `Regex` I am using replaces all *Unicode* non-alphanumeric characters as defined by the the [table of Unicode character categories](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/20bw873z%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#CategoryOrBlock).  For more options, including removing all non-ASCII, non-alphanumeric characters, see [How do I strip non-alphanumeric characters (including spaces) from a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8779189/how-do-i-strip-non-alphanumeric-characters-including-spaces-from-a-string).

Note that if, by removing non-alphanumeric characters from property names, your contract resolver attempts to add duplicate extension data keys, a `JsonSerializationException: Error setting value in extension data ---> System.ArgumentException: An item with the same key has already been added` will get thrown.

Comment: You are awesome ! Thank you very much !

Answer (score 0):

Sure! You can use regex. You can use `[^a-zA-Z0-9]` to match any non-alphanumeric character, and replace it with an empty string. In your `JsonConverter`, you can create a `JObject` and iterate over it's properties, replacing them with ones with a corrected name.

I came up with a generic solution which accepts a `Regex` object and a `replacement` string as constructor parameters:

**Implementation:**

```
class DictionaryRegexReplaceJsonConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public Regex ReplacingRegex { get; set; }
    public string Replacement { get; set; }

    public DictionaryRegexReplaceJsonConverter(Regex replacingRegex, string replacement = "")
    {
        ReplacingRegex = replacingRegex;
        Replacement = replacement;
    }

    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return objectType.IsGenericType && objectType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(Dictionary<,>);
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        var jo = JToken.ReadFrom(reader);
        foreach (JToken token in jo.ToList())
        {
            string replacedName = ReplacingRegex.Replace(token.Path, Replacement);
            JProperty newToken = new JProperty(replacedName, token.First);
            token.Replace(newToken);
        }
        return jo.ToObject(objectType);
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException();
    }
}
```

**Usage:**

```
Regex regex = new Regex("[^a-zA-Z0-9]");
var converter = new DictionaryKeyReplacingJsonConverter(regex);
string json = "{\"dc:title\":\"My Document title\", \"Another Example!\": \"foo\"}";

// {"dctitle": "My Document title", "AnotherExample": "foo"} ]
var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, object>>(json, converter);
```

If performance is of concern, this could be more optimized by manually reading from the `JsonReader` and forming your object, rather than using JObject and replacing properties.

Comment: Thank you. That works pretty well if i follow your code. Is there a way to combine it with the ExtensionData Attribute ?

[JsonExtensionData]
public Dictionary<string, object> Metadata { get; set; } i tried to add a [JsonConverter(typeof(MyConverter)] but that does not to be recognized :-(